# Questions about making 'if user is online' system

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Please help start in the right way . I want to add 'if user is online' system. Which I will use to prevent multiple logins under 1 name, also this system will add option to users showing them who is online at the moment.

I understand that I need mysql table where I will store online users. But how can I understand each second if user is still here? if he logs out then ok, it's easy, but if he will restart? or something else ? So how can I controll all users and understand per second their status ?

**UPDATE** After some discussions with Cupcake I decided to have only who's online feature, letting 1 user to log in multiple times, cause it's difficult to prevent him from doing that in a comfortable way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do, which is what I sometimes do, is this, in the user table have a column named `session_hash` or something similar.

And each time the user logs in, generate a new session hash yourself or use the `session_id` PHP has, as long as you use `session_start` on each page.

Then to retrieve the users row from the database, have a cookie with that session_hash.

---

Example

Login form

```
Username:  [       ]
Password:  [       ]
Remember?: [*]
           [ Login ]
```

PHP page does the following

```
User logs in ->
  System generates a session_id or "salt"
  Updates the users row with the session_id or "salt" value

  Check if the value of the "remember" checkbox is true ->
    Sets a cookie with that session_id or "salt" with a month or so expiration date
  Otherwise just create a normal cookie with the value
```

Then on each page do the following

```
Check if the session_id or "salt" cookie is set ->
  If it is, fetch the users row from the database
    SELECT * FROM users WHERE session_id/"salt" = value of cookie
```

What all this does if lets the user choose if they want to be remembered each visit, if they do create a cookie that doesn't expire for at least a month that way they will be remembered next time they come to the site, but if they login from another browser or computer the "salt" won't be valid on the other computer.

Comment: I also have "salt" called security . Maybe it is better to put salt fingerprint in database instead of putting session ID ?

Comment: If the "salt" column is for the password you shouldn't use it anywhere else.

Comment: no it's not a password. I'll explain. User loggs in using username and password. IF they are correct, salt method generates session id and fingerpint. then later every time user wants something, ssytem checks if the fingerprint is the same and regenerates session id. SO useless to use id cause it is changing all the time. but fingerprint will be the same. so probably I must check fingerprint ?

Comment: So basically the salt is a hash kind of thing that is regenerated at each login? if so use that in a cookie and just fetch the users information with the value of the cookie, that way if they were to login from another browser or computer the other login session wont be valid as it has the old "salt" value.

Comment: what about this ? User logged in. Then restarted his PC and logs in again in a minute. I think system will not let him access correct? And if so then it is bad. What can we do with this ?

Comment: Cause fingeprint is generating randomly each time user logs in.

Comment: Take a look at the example I put in my post, hopefully that will explain things a bit better.

Comment: Example. User logs in. then PC crash. Then he turns on laptop and trying to log in. What happen ?

Comment: What all this does if lets the user choose if they want to be remembered each visit, if they do create a cookie that doesn't expire for at least a month that way they will be remembered next time they come to the site, but if they login from another browser or computer the "salt" won't be valid on the other computer.  ///////////////////// So how do hey log in ?

Comment: I was trying to say, if they login on Computer A, then login on Computer B, they won't be logged in on Computer A anymore, thus only allowing one active session.

Comment: thus this method is bad, so probably I will leave it as is. and active user table will have only user_id I think, just telling users who's online. I think it's enough

Answer (score 2):

renew this table record each time user requests a page, updating access time field.
delete from this table all records which access time field is older than some reasonable timeout like 5 min

to prevent multiple logins under 1 name you have to store session id in the users table. 
when user logins, stire current session id in this field
every time user requests a page, compare this id against actual session id, and make user relogin

Comment: I also have "salt" called security . Maybe it is better to put salt fingerprint in database instead of putting session ID ?

Comment: cause session id is changing all the time. session_regenerate_id();  starts each time I check user.

Answer (score 0):

Simply invalidate all old sessions of the user, once he opens a new one. In that way, he can only run one session (aka one login) at a time.